# SSH session echo back cut-paste buffered commands

Tags: ssh, terminal

I notice a very peculiar behavior in some terminal programs, which I am trying to figure out. Sometimes when I paste a set of commands to a terminal it echoes them back right away before running them one by one.

Example.
Pasting the following:

```
echo "Hello1"
echo "Hello1"
echo "Hello1"
echo "Hello1"
for i in `seq 1 10`; do sleep 1; done
echo "Hello1"
echo "Hello2"
echo "Hello1"
echo "Hello1"
echo "Hello1"
```

The result is this:

```
root@lev-host:~# echo "Hello1"
Hello1
root@lev-host:~# echo "Hello1"
Hello1
root@lev-host:~# echo "Hello1"
Hello1
root@lev-host:~# echo "Hello1"
Hello1
root@lev-host:~# for i in `seq 1 10`; do sleep 1; done
echo "Hello1"
echo "Hello2"
echo "Hello1"
echo "Hello1"
echo "Hello1"
root@lev-host:~# echo "Hello1"
Hello1
root@lev-host:~# echo "Hello2"
Hello2
root@lev-host:~# echo "Hello1"
Hello1
root@lev-host:~# echo "Hello1"
Hello1
root@lev-host:~#
```

So those lines right after the for loop is that one that I am somewhat confused about. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the lines you pasted into the shell. They are written as you "wrote" them, but since the terminal is blocked by the `sleep`, they are send, but not yet read by terminal (the line doesn't start with prompt). They will get written once more, as soon as the other side will read them (the lines starting with the prompt).

What is the actual question? Or you needed just explanation?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but the I guess my not very well articulated question is why does certain terminals actually echo these commands back, but others paste line-by-line and using newline as a marker to wait for the prompt?

Comment: hmm. As I try it, it just doesn't do the described thing and waits. In what terminal do you see this behaviour?

Comment: Ah, here is the fun part. Putty(both mac and widows) and MacOS Terminal exhibit that behavior, but Google Chrome terminal emulator and gnome terminal don't seem to have this problem.

Comment: Echoing is the expected behavior (PuTTY and Terminal.app are correct).

Comment: At the end of the day it is just tty doing the echo-back. However in this case it was a tty driver implementation, which had a bug and was giving some strange echo-back, which was incomplete. I never wanted to know this much about tty. So in the end this answer is a good way of explaining what is happening.

Comment: Is tere a way to stop ssh from echoing back?

Comment: @fakedrake you can use stty to change the tty settings. If you use `-echo`, it will not echo what you write, similarly as you input passwords in terminal.

Comment: Thank you, I found it out eventually. The solution is quite simple but extremely hard to google. The main issue I had was that the `-s` argument of `read` led me to believe that the shell is responsible for the echo-back rather than the terminal (which is not the case).